# Is there any difference between custom Modal Dialog in SharePoint 2010 and 2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, modal-dialog

In SP2010 we used the code as:-

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function OpenDialog(URL) {
       var NewPopUp = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
       NewPopUp.url = URL;
       NewPopUp.width = 700;
       NewPopUp.height = 350;
       SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(NewPopUp);
   }
 </script>
```

I read article to open modal dialog in SP2013:-

```
function dialogfunction(pageUrl) {
var options = { url: pageUrl, width: 800, height: 600 };
SP.SOD.execute('sp.ui.dialog.js', 'SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog', options);
}
```

Is there something changed in the way we do this in SP2013? (SP.SOD.execute???)

Comment: Have a look at http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/11/17/using-the-dialog-framework-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx, this will clear all your doubts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK nothing has changed in Dialog Framework in SharePoint 2013..

You can use SP.SOD.execute in SharePoint 2010 as well, remember we used to use `executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded` function to make sure the JS file is loaded before our function gets called.. This function is also a part of SP.SOD built-in JS class.. `execute` is also a part of this class, the author just made it clear by adding SP.SOD at the beginning

Please have a look at [SP.SOD Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff408081%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

**UPDATE**

Here is the simplest example

```
<script type="text/javascript">

//User Defined Function to Open Dialog Framework
function OpenDialog(strPageURL) 
{
  var dialogOptions = SP.UI.$create_DialogOptions();
  dialogOptions.url = strPageURL;// URL of the Page
  dialogOptions.width = 750; // Width of the Dialog
  dialogOptions.height = 500; // Height of the Dialog
  dialogOptions.dialogReturnValueCallback = Function.createDelegate( null, CloseCallback); // Function to capture dialog closed event
  SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(dialogOptions); // Open the Dialog
  return false;
}

// Dialog close event capture function
function CloseCallback(strReturnValue, target) 
{
  if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.OK) // Perform action on Ok.
    {
   alert("User clicked Ok!");
    }
  if (strReturnValue === SP.UI.DialogResult.cancel) // Perform action on Cancel.
   {
   alert( "User clicked Cancel!");
   }
}

</script>
```

You can see all the available parameteres on [SP.UI.ModalDialog.showModalDialog(options) Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff410058%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

If you want to go in-depth, these should help:

[Tips & Tricks: SharePoint 2010 Modal Dialogs](http://blog.collabware.com/2012/10/30/tips-tricks-sharepoint-2010-modal-dialogs/)
[Using the Dialog Framework in SharePoint 2010](http://www.chaholl.com/archive/2010/11/17/using-the-dialog-framework-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx)

PS: All applies to SharePoint 2013 as well

Comment: can you provide me with a reference links that shows the best practice approach of using the modal dialog and its properties.

Comment: check the update